# get the name of the output variable in R

Tags: r

sorry for my poor english

Is there a way in R to get the name used to the returning values of a function within the function, the same way you can catch the name of the input variables with "substitute"??. I mean something like this "outputname" function:

```
myFun=function(x){
  nameIN=substitute(x)
  nameOUT=outputname()
  out=x*2
  cat("The name of the input is ", nameIN,"   and this is the value:\n")
  print(x)
  cat("The name of the output is ", nameOUT, "and this is the value:\n")
  print(out)
  return(out)
}
```

This is what I wish:

```
> myINPUT=12;
> myOUTPUT=myFun(myINPUT)
The name of the input is  myINPUT and this is the value:
[1] 12
The name of the output is  myOUTPUT and this is the value:
[1] 24


> myOUTPUT
[1] 24
```

I've been looking for an answer and I am going crazy. It seems something so simple but I
can't find anything.

Thanks

Comment: It's not possible, at least not within the function called.

Comment: You can't do this. The next best thing would be to pass myOUTPUT by reference as an argument to myFun and use substitute to get its name.

Comment: Could you use `assign` instead of `=` or `<-`? In contrast to the primitives it has named arguments.

Comment: Thank you. I will try "by reference" and "assign" advices.

Comment: @gpf consider @Roland's suggestion. If you use `assign`, inside `myFun` you can call `sys.calls` to access the parent calls and extract the name of the variable you're assigning to.

Comment: I haven't learned to use `magrittr` pipe tools yet, but isn't there some pipe tool that gets the  result of the previous statement? In which case you might be able to retrieve via a "backwards-looking" pipe command.

Comment: BTW,  the output object doesn't even exist until the function is complete.  That is, for `foo<-bar(x)` , `foo` doesn't get created until the `return` call.  You can verify this via `xfoo<-function(x) {print(ls(pat='xjk',env=.GlobalEnv));return(x)}` followed with `xjk<-xfoo('something')`

Answer (score 2):

Here are two workarounds from the comments. This first uses environments to pass by reference. The output variable is supplied as an argument to `myFun1`. The second uses `assign` to assign the return value of `myFun2` to the output variable and retrieves the name of the ouput variable by examining the call stack.

```
myINPUT <- 12
```

**Workaround 1**

```
myFun1 <- function(x, output){
  nameIN=substitute(x)
  nameOUT=substitute(output)
  output$value=x*2
  cat("The name of the input is ", nameIN,"   and this is the value:\n")
  print(x)
  cat("The name of the output is ", nameOUT, "and this is the value:\n")
  print(output$value)
}

myOUTPUT <- new.env()
myOUTPUT$value <- 1
myFun1(myINPUT, myOUTPUT)
# The name of the input is  myINPUT    and this is the value:
# [1] 12
# The name of the output is  myOUTPUT and this is the value:
# [1] 24
myOUTPUT$value
# [1] 24
```

**Workaround 2**

Suggested by @Roland (my interpretation of his comment, at least):

```
myFun2=function(x){
  nameIN=substitute(x)
  nameOUT=as.list(sys.calls()[[1]])[[2]]
  out=x*2
  cat("The name of the input is ", nameIN,"   and this is the value:\n")
  print(x)
  cat("The name of the output is ", nameOUT, "and this is the value:\n")
  print(out)
  return(out)
}

assign('myOUTPUT', myFun2(myINPUT))
# The name of the input is  myINPUT    and this is the value:
# [1] 12
# The name of the output is  myOUTPUT and this is the value:
# [1] 24
myOUTPUT
# [1] 24
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not exactly what I was looking for but those are good solutions. I had another idea.. give the name of the output as an argument and then, assign the value to it ussing "assign(outPUT_name,out,envir=parent.frame())".

```
myFun=function(x,outPUT_name){
  nameIN=substitute(x)
  out=x*2
  cat("The name of the input is ", nameIN,"   and this is the value:\n")
  print(x)
  cat("The name of the output is ", outPUT_name, "and this is the value:\n")
  print(out)
  assign(outPUT_name,out,envir=parent.frame())
}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
myFun(myINPUT,'myOUTPUT')
```

May be I am a little bit capricious but I wanted not to have to add the output name as an argument... it's a shame there's no way to acomplish that

Thank you very much